# I cant open discord using python

Tags: python

I have been trying to make an app that opens all the essential apps at just executing the python file so i dont have to click each one.

I have tried:

```
import os
os.system('Discord.exe')
```

Yet it doesnt work and i have also tried subprocess:

```
import subprocess
path_to_discord = os.path.abspath("C:\\Windows\\System32\discord.exe")
subprocess.Popen(path_to_discord)
```

and every guide opens things like notepad or calculator so i dont really know what to do.

Comment: What is the exception that is raised? `FileNotFoundError` or anything else?
Also can you open other applications using your code?

Comment: Yes i have ran others like my browser and notepad, i cant seem to open discord though. the error here is "'Discord.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command" on os.

Comment: What about this path? `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Discord\app-x.x.xxx\Discord.exe`

Comment: i have tried that, and it doesnt work.

Comment: I doubt that it didn't work. What made you think that Discord would be located under `system32`? That's a system folder and not for userspace apps.
@meshkati Has provided you with the correct answer. That is where Discord is located under normal conditions.